# How to open each screenshots folder with my android app?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent

I have explored my device folders and saw I have two `screenshots` folders:

`//storage/sdcard0/pictures/Screenshots/ ...`

`//storage/extSdCard/DCIM/Screenshots/ ...`

I understand one of them points to built-in Sd card

and the other to extra Sd card I have bout and added to my device.

I'm building an android app that has two buttons:

1) open local screenShots

2) open extra SD screenShots

I have managed to write code only for the first button.

How can I open the second one?

```
  private void GetWithFileExplorer()
            {
                File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Pictures/Screenshots");
                Log.d("File path ", dir.getPath());
                String dirPath=dir.getAbsolutePath();
                if(dir.exists() && dir.isDirectory()) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, null);
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    intent.setData(Uri.fromFile(dir));

                    Log.d("b4performSpecificCrop_startActivityForResult::", Integer.toString(3));
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 3);
                    Log.d("afterperformSpecificCrop_startActivityForResult::", Integer.toString(3));
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
getExternalStorageDirectory()
```

and

```
getCacheDir()
```